# Transpose a vector A into B in inverse order

Tags: c, vector

I have a vector A with 6 positions with respective values {10,20,30,40,50,60}, and initially I have a vector B of 4 positions with the respective values {0,0,0,0}, My problem is that I need to transpose the values from vector A to vector B in reverse order. Using a for-loop would look like this:

```
i = 0:

B = {10,0,0,0}

i = 1:

B = {20,10,0,0}

i = 2:

B = {30,20,10,0}

i = 3:

B = {40,30,20,10}

i = 4:

B = {50, 40, 30, 20}

i = 5:

B = {60,50,40,30}
```

I'm doing this to implement a vibrato audio effect in C ,I have the algorithm in Matlab, in Matlab there is a specific function for this, which is:

```
B = [A (n); B (1: L-1)];
```

For:

```
N = size of A

L = size of B
```

So, could anyone tell me if there is any function ready to do this in C?

Comment: @IAGO SESTREM Ochoa In fact C is an assembler among high-level languages. Most of algorithms you have to write yourself.:)

Comment: Apologies, but why are you trying to do this in C?  I ask because the solution is about 6 lines of C code and trivial for anyone with any knowledge of C, therefore we assume you are doing it in C with almost no knowledge of the language for some other reason?

Comment: @MichaelDorgan I need to implement a vibrato audio effect, the only thing left to finish the C implementation is that function, but it seems that it doesn't exists in C language. I've used 6 lines to exemplify, in the original code is something about 44120 lines in vector A and 665 line in vector B, I am not asking about a complete code, I just want to know, if there is a function like this in C, or I need to implement that by myself.

Comment: It seems simple enough to be a 1st exercise in any 'introduction to c' course. Have you  ever written c before? If not, look for a beginner tutorial for 'hello, world', 'arrays' and 'for loops'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no ready function to do this in C.  You will need to write a simple function that returns an array of 4 values (integers?  hard to say) and accepts an array of 6 values.  You may be able to find an external library that does this for you, but I doubt it because of the simplicity of this function.